# JQuery- is it possible to grab a nested sibling element after an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I'm running into a problem with an old web forms app that I am adding some functionality to.

I have a table that is dynamically populated from a database and lives in a DataGrid. I'm attempting to add a drop down carrot that will show a certain section of the table when clicked. The problem is, the ID is set dynamically by the ASCX file/or it is going to not be unique so I am trying to figure out a creative way to grab it and display it.

[image: need to find this p tag]

Is it possible to grab the sibling p with a class name of problemDescription after clicking on P above?

I've tried using combinations of this function but that just returns either nothing, or the .problemdescription from the next row.

```
function expandDescription(buttonClick) {
        //returns the problem description from the next row
        $(buttonClick).closest('tr').next().find('.problemDescription')
        //does not find anything
        $(buttonClick).closest('td').next().find('.problemDescription')
        //does not find anything
        $(buttonClick).closest('p')
        //does not find anything
        $(buttonClick).next('p')
        //does not find anything
        $(buttonClick).closest('.problemDescription')
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You want `$(buttonClick).closest('tr').find('.problemDescription')`

Comment: thanks @charlietfl that was it! If you write the answer below I'll accept it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(buttonClick).closest('tr').find('.problemDescription')